# JavaScript - Function to form an array based on 3 arrays (merging)

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given the following js arrays:

```
var prices_A =[
['company','100g','200g','300g'],
['business_a','40€','50€',''],
['business_b','50€','61€','42€'],
['business_c','66€','','31€']
]

var prices_B =[
['company','100g','200g','300g'],
['business_b','40€','50€',''],
['business_d','50€','61€','42€'],
['business_e','66€','','31€']
]

var prices_C =[
['company','100g','200g','300g'],
['business_e','40€','50€',''],
['business_b','66€','','31€']
]
```

How can I make a function passing two variables: grams and price_type, returning an array merging the arrays based on the input (variables passed). The price_type can be: prices_A, prices_B, prices_C or prices_all. When prices_all is introduced, it should query merging all the prices (prices_A, prices_B, and prices_C)

**Example 1:**

```
var prices = myfunction(200,prices_C){}
```

Result:

```
prices =[
['company','200g'],
['business_e','50€']
]
```

**Example 2:**

```
var prices = myfunction(100,prices_all){}
```

Result:

```
prices =[
['company','100g_A','100g_B','100g_C'],
['business_a','40€',''],
['business_b','50€','40€','66€'],
['business_c','66€',''],
['business_d','','50€',''],
['business_e','','66€','40€'],
]
```

Comment: what does `prices_all` look like?

Comment: @NickParsons it seems like it's just all of these combined. Although, honestly, that's the only thing I think I get from the question. I'm lost on what is actually the goal here.

Comment: prices_all is not an array. It just indicates the function has to merge the three arrays.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Have you thought about converting your arrays to hold objects instead of strings? Meaning, instead of each array element being an array itself, make it an object. One for company, one for business. Each object will have specific keys which you can access easily and therefore make it easier to do what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution which gets a price for a group, if given or for all groups and then it assigns these groups to a single array.

```js
function getPrices(weight, category) {

    function getByGroup(group) {
        var index = group[0].indexOf(weight);
        return group
            .map(a => [0, index].map(i => a[i]))
            .filter(a => a[1]);
    }

    return category in allPrices
        ? getByGroup(allPrices[category])
        : Object.entries(allPrices).reduce((r, [k, group], i) => {
            var temp = getByGroup(group),
                index;

            if (!temp.length) return r;
            temp[0][1] += '_' + k.slice(-1);
            if (!r) return temp;
            index = r[0].push(temp[0][1]) - 1;            
            temp.forEach(([company, price]) => {
                var row = r.find(([c]) => c === company);
                if (!row) {
                    r.push(row = [company]);
                } 
                row[index] = price;
            });
            r.forEach(a => a[index] = a[index] || '');
            return r;
        }, undefined);
}


var prices_A = [['company', '100g', '200g', '300g'], ['business_a', '40€', '50€', ''], ['business_b', '50€', '61€', '42€'], ['business_c', '66€', '', '31€']],
    prices_B = [['company', '100g', '200g', '300g'], ['business_b', '40€', '50€', ''], ['business_d', '50€', '61€', '42€'], ['business_e', '66€', '', '31€']],
    prices_C = [['company', '100g', '200g', '300g'], ['business_e', '40€', '50€', ''], ['business_b', '66€', '', '31€']],
    allPrices = { prices_A, prices_B, prices_C };

console.log(getPrices('200g', 'prices_C'));
console.log(getPrices('100g', 'prices_all'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks for your support! However, it does not work when the arrays are not ordered. For example, change values of grams like in prices_A 100g,200g,500g. in prices_b, 100g, 1000g, 2000g.

Comment: you could search for the exact weight string with a unit. please see edit.

Comment: thanks again, but it does not work. Look, change prices_c to: prices_C = [
      ['company', '100g', '200g', '500g'],
      ['bussines_e', '40€', '50€', ''],
      ['bussines_b', '66€', '', '31€']
    ], and query this: alert(getPrices('500', 'prices_all'));

Comment: you need the unit inside of the weight string as well. take `'500g'`.

Comment: the same result.

Comment: Just a small question. It is returning "" when it has not a value. How could I change the "" for 0. Thanks! https://prnt.sc/o3twzn

Comment: replace this to `r.forEach(a => a[index] = a[index] || 0);` with a zero as default value.